# Can I force the execution of an active record query chain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an edge case where I want to use `.first` **only after** my SQL query has been executed.

My case is the next one:

```
User.select("sum((type = 'foo')::int) as foo_count",
            "sum((type = 'bar')::int) as bar_count")
    .first
    .yield_self { |r| r.bar_count / r.foo_count.to_f }
```

However, this would throw an SQL error saying that I should include my user_id in the `GROUP BY` clause. I've already found a hacky solution using `to_a`, but I really wonder if there is a proper way to force execution before my call to `.first`.

Comment: Does `pluck` work instead of `select`?

Comment: Yes it does! `User.pluck("sum((type = 'foo')::int)::float / sum((type = 'bar')::int)::float").first` did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because [`first`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first) uses an order by statement to order by `id`.

> "Find the first record (or first N records if a parameter is supplied). If no order is defined it will order by primary key."

Instead try [`take`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-take)

> "Gives a record (or N records if a parameter is supplied) without any implied order. The order will depend on the database implementation. If an order is supplied it will be respected."

So

```
User.select("sum((type = 'foo')::int) as foo_count",
        "sum((type = 'bar')::int) as bar_count")
.take
.yield_self { |r| r.bar_count / r.foo_count.to_f }
```

should work appropriately however as stated the order is indeterminate.

Comment: I don't care about the order since I have only one result in my collection anyway!

Comment: @UlysseBN I certainly can see that. The commentary was more for others that stumble across this answer in the future

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [`pluck`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) which retrieves only the data instead of [`select`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) which just alters which fields get loaded into *models*:

```
User.pluck(
  "sum((type = 'foo')::int) as foo_count",
  "sum((type = 'bar')::int) as bar_count"
).map do |foo_count, bar_count|
  bar_count / foo_count.to_f 
end
```

You can probably do the division in the query as well if necessary.